# How to animate a child view and having the parent view to automatically resize?

Tags: android

I've a quick question.

I'm trying to animating a child view to make it disappear. That part is easy, but, during the animation, the parent view is not resized. How can I do to make the parent view automtically resize during the animation?

Here is my current code:

```
    AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(true);

    Animation fade = new ScaleAnimation(1.f, 1.f, 1.f, 0);        
    Animation fade2 = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);

    set.addAnimation(fade);
    set.addAnimation(fade2);
    set.setDuration(2000);
    set.setFillAfter(true);        

    bgColor.startAnimation(set);
```

bgColor is the View I'm making disappear. Here is the final result :
[Result](http://img31.imageshack.us/img31/9876/devicez.png)

You can see the gap after the animation.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi.. Did u have any luck with this?
I'm trying to do the same...

Answer (score 0):

You may add an AnimationListener and do a change of the layout after the animation is done

```
animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        bgColor.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
    }
});
```

Also, be sure to have your stuff together regarding onFillAfter()!